# local volatility not reasonable

Tags: options, local-volatility, call

We are going to generate synthetic option prices using a **Heston** model, i.e.,
$$
\begin{gather*}
dS_t = \sqrt{v_t} S_t dZ_t,\\
dv_t = \lambda (\mu - v_t) d_t + \eta \sqrt{v_t} dW_t,
\end{gather*}
$$
where $Z,W$ are standard Brownian motions with $\langle Z,\, W\rangle_t = \rho t$, $S_0 = 1$, $v_0$ as an additional parameter.

**Standing assumption:** $r = 0$.

We compute option prices by the COS method, and then use finite difference quotients to estimate the derivatives $\partial_t C(t,K)$ and $\partial_{KK} C(t,K)$.

For a very small maturity $T$ of a call option with strike $K$, log-moneyness is given by $log(S/K) =0.8$, where $S$

The local volatility is then not defined and gives an nan values.

$log(S_0/K) =0.8$ would mean that $S_0/K = 2.2$ so the option is far in the money.

Why do I get an undefined local volatility then?

Maybe such a far in the money option is unreasonable for very little maturity?

Comment: Could you explain your model and what you mean by not defined? Is it giving nan, inf ?

Comment: Your question is not really clear, please edit in your clarifying comments and specify your inputs.

Comment: @user61159 . A good test to see if there is a chance to back out a volatility from a price given a maturity and moneyness is to see if the option price is sensitive to the volatility at all. For far ITM / OTM and short maturities this is often not the case.

Comment: @KurtG. So in this example the volatility should not be rather low? What would happen in a real financial market in this case?

Comment: @user61159 . We don't know enough details about your example. You can easily make the test I suggested. In general : if your option pricing shows zero sensitivity to a vol and you want to invert that function to map a price to vol, what do you think should happen? There cannot be an answer. Constant functions cannot be inverted.

Comment: Thank you. But if we would leave out this simulation and focus on a real financial market. The vol of  a far in the money option for very short maturity  must be high. This seems to be unlikely isnt it?

Comment: The Black-Scholes formula is 50 years old. Please take it use a very short maturity and a far ITM option. Does the price change when you change the vol? Show me the market that quotes a vol for such an option.

Comment: It does not change, but what does it mean ?